# Retrieve IP information over bluecat restAPI

Tags: rest, networking

How can I get information from a specific IP `192.168.178.20` over bluecat API v2 the like MAC-address, host name and other related fields?

I tested the examples from the [documentation](https://docs.bluecatnetworks.com/r/Address-Manager-RESTful-v2-API-Guide/Filter/9.5.0):

`GET http://{Address_Manager_IP}/api/v2/networks?filter=range:contains("192.168.178.20")`

`GET http://{Address_Manager_IP}/api/v2/addresses?filter=address:ge('192.168.178.0') and address:le('192.168.178.255')`

The problem is, both GET calls return zero results, but I can see the data in the web interface:
IP Space - Range 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.178.0/24 - 192.168.178.20

I would expect a json with fields:

- IP 192.168.178.8
- mac-address
- host name
- ... and other IP related information
- IP 192.168.178.10
- mac-address
- host name
- ... and other IP related information
- ...